# Row matrix and move in row matrix

Tags: java, arrays, string, matrix

I want to write a method that will move the zero in all 4 directions And update the map by moving the zero in the console, how do I do this?

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[][] map = {
                {".",".","."},
                {".","0","."},
                {".",".","."}
        };
        for(int i=0;i<map.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<map[i].length;j++){
                System.out.print(map[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

there are no restrictions or anything, I just want to figure out how to move the zero, by any means.

Comment: What means _**move the zero in all 4 directions**_ ? How dose the expected result look like?

Comment: well, if I want to move it up, then the zero in the map rises 1 block higher. If lower, then lower. And if I want to move him when he is at the barrier, then he appears on the other side. 
Something similar to the snake game, only without glasses, and without increasing the snake itself, and in the console.

Comment: This is just a 2d array. Take a look at what each index is actually doing. The first index is selecting one of the sub-arrays, and the second index is selecting a value within that sub-array. The way you have it laid out, this means the first index represents vertical movement, and the second one represents horizontal movement. For example, your 0 is currently at `map[1][1]`. Keeping in mind what I said before, to move it up you can place it at `map[0][1]`. To move down you put it at `map[2][1]`. Left and right is the same but with the second index instead of the first.

Comment: You can read more about the concept of 2d arrays [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mrmiller/15-110/Handouts/arrays2D.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've written will just attempt the printing of your matrix. If you want to move the "0" element around your matrix, you first need to define an `enum` to establish the direction and then a method `move()` that given a direction `d` and a matrix `m` will move the "0" element accordingly.

The element movement is just a rotation that increments or decrements the respective index by taking care of the edge cases (the row and column's bounds).

```
public class Main {

    public enum Direction {
        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
    }

    public static void move(Direction move, String[][] matrix) {
        int row = -1, col = -1, newRow, newCol;
        String temp;

        //Finding the position of the "0" element
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j].equals("0")) {
                    row = i;
                    col = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (row != -1) break;
        }

        //If not 0 element is found then the method is terminated
        if (row < 0 || col < 0) {
            return;
        }

        switch (move) {
            case UP:
                newRow = row - 1 < 0 ? matrix.length - 1 : row - 1;
                temp = matrix[newRow][col];
                matrix[newRow][col] = matrix[row][col];
                matrix[row][col] = temp;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                newRow = (row + 1) % matrix.length;
                temp = matrix[newRow][col];
                matrix[newRow][col] = matrix[row][col];
                matrix[row][col] = temp;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                newCol = col - 1 < 0 ? matrix[row].length - 1 : col - 1;
                temp = matrix[row][newCol];
                matrix[row][newCol] = matrix[row][col];
                matrix[row][col] = temp;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                newCol = (col + 1) % matrix[row].length;
                temp = matrix[row][newCol];
                matrix[row][newCol] = matrix[row][col];
                matrix[row][col] = temp;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Here is a link testing a possible implementation

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/s63